# XAML, Binding, Source and Path

Tags: xaml, mvvm, binding, maui, .net-maui

I am learning to understand, how the binding mechanism works in XAML for .NET MAUI. I am assuming this is the same for all XAML projects, WPF, MAUI etc.

At the end is the whole XAML.

This XAML works fine:

```
<Button WidthRequest="150" Text="Add Activity" 
                Command="{Binding AddActivityEntityCommand}"
                IsEnabled="{Binding IsNotBusy}"
                Grid.Row="2"
                Margin="8"/>
```

- Is the reason why this works because the Button is part of the ContentPage, which has it's `x:DataType` set to `MainPageViewModel`, which is where the command lives?
- The Binding is set to `AddActivityEntityCommand`, while the actual method signature is

  `async Task AddActivityEntityAsync()`. How is this resolved? Since it obviously doesn't match the name, but it works. And what are the method signature requirements for this to work/being recognized?

This on the other hand, doesn't just work as easy out of the box:

```
<Label HorizontalOptions="End" TextColor="Red" Padding="0,0,10,0" Text="" 
       IsVisible="{Binding IsSynchronized}">
            <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                 <TapGestureRecognizer 
                       Command="{Binding Source={x:Type viewmodel:MainPageViewModel},
                                            Path=DeleteActivityCommand}" />
            </Label.GestureRecognizers>
 </Label>
```

- In this context, adding `Command="{Binding DeleteActivityCommand}` doesn't work, because it derives its Path from `<DataTemplate x:DataType="model:ActivityEntity">`, I am assuming, which is the data object and not the ViewModel, where the command actually is.
- The problem here is, that as soon as I enter this XAML `Command="{Binding Source={x:Type viewmodel:MainPageViewModel}, Path=DeleteActivityCommand}"`, the CollectionView shows empty and there is an unhandled exception thrown when the view is loaded:

> System.Reflection.TargetException: Object does not match target type.

- The method signature for this command is this `async Task DeleteActivityAsync()`

What am I missing?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage
    x:Class="OnesieMobile.View.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:model="clr-namespace:OnesieMobile.Model"
    xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:OnesieMobile.ViewModel"
    x:DataType="viewmodel:MainPageViewModel"
    Title="{Binding Title}">
    <Grid
        ColumnDefinitions="*"
        RowDefinitions="20,50,50,*"
        RowSpacing="0">
        <Label HorizontalOptions="End" Margin="10,0,10,0"  Text="{Binding CurrentDateTime}" Grid.Row="0"/>
        <Entry Margin="10,0,10,0" 
            Grid.Row="1"  x:Name="entryNewActivity" 
            Placeholder="New Activityssss" HeightRequest="30" Text="{Binding NewActivityTitle}" />

        <Button WidthRequest="150" Text="Add Activity" 
                    Command="{Binding AddActivityEntityCommand}"
                    IsEnabled="{Binding IsNotBusy}"
                    Grid.Row="2"
                    Margin="8"/>

        <CollectionView
            Grid.Row="3"
                ItemsSource="{Binding ActivityEntities}"
                SelectionMode="None">
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:ActivityEntity">
                    <Grid Padding="10,0,10,0">
                        <Frame Style="{StaticResource CardView}">
                            <Grid  ColumnDefinitions="*,30,50">
                                <StackLayout Padding="10,5,0,0" Grid.Column="0">
                                    <Label Text="{Binding Title}"  />
                                </StackLayout>
                                <StackLayout Padding="10,5,0,0" Grid.Column="1">
                                    <Label HorizontalOptions="End" TextColor="Red"
                                           Padding="0,0,10,0" Text="" IsVisible="{Binding IsSynchronized}"  >
                                        <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                                            <TapGestureRecognizer
                                                Command="{Binding Source={x:Type viewmodel:MainPageViewModel},
                                                Path=DeleteActivityCommand}" />
                                        </Label.GestureRecognizers>
                                    </Label>
                                </StackLayout>
                                <StackLayout Padding="10,5,0,0" Grid.Column="2">
                                    <Label HorizontalOptions="End" 
                                           Padding="0,0,10,0" Text="✔" IsVisible="{Binding IsSynchronized}"  />
                                </StackLayout>
                            </Grid>
                        </Frame>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
        <ActivityIndicator IsVisible="{Binding IsBusy}"
                               IsRunning="{Binding IsBusy}"
                               HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                               VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                               Grid.RowSpan="3"
                               Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>

    </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

**Update:** 
MainPageViewModel.cs contains these Commands

```
[ICommand]
async Task DeleteActivityAsync()
{
}


[ICommand]
async Task AddActivityEntityAsync()
{
}
```

Comment: Can’t answer anything without also seeing the c# that this is binding to. Somewhere, there must be Command declarations - not just those tasks.

Comment: please avoid asking multiple questions in one post - it makes it difficult to provide a concise answer.  Briefly: `DataType` is a helper to assist XAML Intellisense, it does not impact the code at runtime.  At runtime, the `BindingContext` of the page/element is what matters.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve I've updated the question with the C# code. Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: @Jason I don't understand, the only `BindingContext` I can find is in the constructor of MainPage.xaml.cs where it takes the `MainPageViewModel` and sets it to the `BindingContext` of the `ContentPage`. So then, how would I set the `BindingContext` of the element `TapGestureRecognizer`?

Comment: every View element has a `BindingContext` property - however they are inherited in the visual tree, so every child element will inherit it's parents `BindingContext` unless otherwise specified

Comment: normally you would need to explicitly define `ICommand` properties for your commands in your VM, but apparently the `[ICommand]` attribute does some magic and creates them for you

Comment: [OPINION] Ugh, that’s a terrible concept. If its going to create a command, thus requiring a different name, it ought to require programmer to specify the name. Magic name transformations are a minor convenience, not worth it.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve I reused the code from here: https://github.com/jfversluis/dotnet-maui-workshop/blob/main/Part%204%20-%20Platform%20Features/MonkeyFinder/ViewModel/MonkeysViewModel.cs
I thought this is state of the art programming. I don't have an opinion of my own at this point, I still have to understand the different concepts first :)

Comment: I hear you. Clearly Gerald knows things about Maui that I don't know yet. :) Writing an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inside an item template, there are several ways to refer to the original BindingContext. I like to do it by getting it from the collection itself:

```xml
<CollectionView x:Name="myCollection" ...>
    ...
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        ...
        Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference myCollection},
                  Path=BindingContext.DeleteActivityCommand}" />
```

---

FUTURE TBD:

I don't like the command name not existing anywhere in the implementing code. Hopefully there will eventually be a way to *specify* the command name in the ICommand attribute, to make it obvious:

```cs
// This won't work today.
[ICommand Name="DeleteActivityCommand"]
...
```

For now, we have to learn `[ICommand]`'s magic naming rules, which seem to be "Remove `Async` from end (if present); Add `Command` to end".

Comment: Awesome! Thank you. That totally worked. The ICommand attribute is described here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.toolkit.mvvm.input.icommandattribute . It doesn't appear to me, that the name actually can be specified.

Comment: Been looking for this and it worked. Thanks!